# Why have all Asian Games that were held in Bangkok been on Decembers?

Tags: history, asian-games

Four Asian Games have been held in Bangkok overall:

- 1966 Asian Games: December 9 - 20
- 1970 Asian Games: December 9 - 20
- 1978 Asian Games: December 9 - 20
- 1998 Asian Games: December 6 - 20

All other Asian Games have varying dates; but these four have almost exact dates.

Are the mentioned opening and closing dates related to Thailand's history and culture or there is another specific reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[King Bhumibol Adulyadej](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhumibol_Adulyadej), the king of Thailand during all four of those Asian Games, celebrated his birthday on December 5. I therefore strongly suspect that those Games were timed to begin shortly after his birthday - while I haven't found any corroborating evidence so far, it seems unlikely to have been a coincidence.